# How do you loop when some column changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

View:

```
<% @foods.each do |f| %>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>food name</td>
   <td>price</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <%= food.name %>
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= food.price %>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

`@foods` has `food_category_id` (value is 1, 2, 3, ...) and many foods belong to each category. When `food_category_id` changes during loop, I want to add headline for the each category on the top of table or add one space between previous category to be easy to see. And those `food_category_id` will increase/decrease in the future.

How do you loop this situation? I have a few idea but not sure what is better idea.

For example, Appetizer is 1 of food_category_id. Pasta is 2 of food_category_id.

This is what I expect:

```
Appetizer <- I want to add this headline when category_id changes
food name  price 
aaaa        $3
bbbb        $2
cccc        $1

Pasta <- I want to add this headline when category_id changes
food name  price 
aaaa        $3
bbbb        $2
cccc        $1
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your structure a bit -

First, define `@foods` as `Food.group_by { |f| f.food_category.name }` (assuming that FoodCategory has an attribute like name, but change that to whatever attribute you use).

Then loop through your foods like this:

```
@foods.each do |category, foods|
  #...your code here
  # remember that `foods` is an Array so you'll loop through that separately
  # foods.each do |food|
  #   ...display food name and price
  # end
end
```